# pass object on contructor in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

i have this code:

```
class AxiosResponseBoardType {
    board: {
      [prop:string]: string | string[] | BoardLoadingType | BoardErrorType;
      created_on: string;
      name: string;
      threads: string[];
      updated_on: string;
      _id: string;
      delete_password: string;
      loading: BoardLoadingType;
      error: BoardErrorType;
    };
    constructor(params: {name: string, delete_password: string, id?: string}) {
      for (var fld in params) {
          this.board = {[fld]: fld}

      }
    }
    genUuidV1 = () => uuidv1();
    now = () => new Date().toISOString();
  }
```

the constructor can receive optional property so i am looping by this code to initialize board:

```
for (var fld in params) {
  this.board = {[fld]: fld}
}
```

how do i make this work?

Comment: What exactly is your problem? How does this not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if params may or may not contain certain properties, board has to have optional properties. That can easily be done using the `Partial` generic type:

```
 board: Partial<{
  [prop:string]: string | string[] | BoardLoadingType | BoardErrorType;
  created_on: string;
  name: string;
  threads: string[];
  updated_on: string;
  _id: string;
  delete_password: string;
  loading: BoardLoadingType;
  error: BoardErrorType;
}>;
```

Now if your intention was to copy `params` to `this.board`, that's easy:

```
 // Initialize `this.board` once:
 this.board = {};
 // Then fill it with params or whatever
 Object.assign(this.board, params);
```

You'll notice that `id` and `_id` do missmatch ...

---

As a sidenote, your code:

```
for (var fld in params) {
 this.board = {[fld]: fld}
}
```

Just doesn't work at all. It'll reset `this.board` at every iteration to a new object, and that object will have keys as values, e.g. if `params` would be `{ name: "test", deleted_password: "secret" }`, then `this.board` would result in `{ deleted_password: "deleted_password" }`. Thats probably not what you wanted, and Typescript tried to prevent that for a reason ...

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a better answer, but since it's dynamic, TypeScript ofc has no way of knowing what property you're setting in the for loop.

There's ways to get around this, such as using `Object.defineProperty()`,  but I normally opt for something like this:

```
  for (var fld in params) {
      this.board = {[fld]: fld} as any
  }
```

EDIT:

You can also declare all the properties besides `[prop:string]` as optional (but I assume this is there simply to try to get it to work?). eg:

```
board: {
      [prop:string]: string | string[] | BoardLoadingType | BoardErrorType;
      created_on?: string;
      name?: string;
      threads?: string[];
      updated_on?: string;
      _id?: string;
      delete_password?: string;
      loading?: BoardLoadingType;
      error?: BoardErrorType;
    };
```

The reason for the error is that you're telling typescript that those properties are absolutely required, and yet you're instantiating the object without them using the for loop.

Hope this helps, interested to see other answers :)

Comment: Prefer using `for(const prop of obj)` instead of for..in, if you're not checking *prop* against `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, prop)`. Also note that *var* inside a *for* doesn't define a new scope, use *let* or *const* instead.

Comment: "TypeScript ofc has no way of knowing what property you're setting in the for loop." for sure it does. `fld` will be a union type of keys

Comment: @Vitim.us you can't iterate objects with `for...of` ... Also `var` doesn't cause any problems here?